# Aurelia skeleton-navigation: gulp watch takes 2min+ to start

Tags: aurelia, browser-sync

I am using aurelia skeleton-es2016. Gulp watch takes at least 2 minutes. I have a dual-core 2.8Ghz amd with 6gb ram.

I initially had issues with missing modules after npm install but fixed those. Not sure if that is relevant to this case.

Also I'm not very experienced with gulp. Are the files being served from the the dist folder? Are those the files being watched by browser-sync for changes? I tried making a change to the index.html page and the change was not reflected in the browser without a reload. Is that file not among the ones watched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s unusual that gulp watch needs so much time.

You should try to reinstall all npm and jspm packages.
If you have problems deleting the `npm_modules` folder you can try the tool I use in this case: [Unlocker](http://www.chip.de/downloads/Unlocker_18414122.html).

The files watched by `browserSync` are in your root folder `.`. You can see that under `skeleton-es2016\build\tasks\serve.js` this serve task is used by the watch task.

Or in your console where you are running gulp watch: `[BS] Serving files from: .`

If you used the newest `skeleton-es2016` you should also have a `browserSync` control App running under http://localhost:3001/

BrowserSync will not detect changes inside your `index.html` file. That´s because of the watch task configuration:

> only files under "src" will be watched.

You can see this configuration under: `skeleton-es2016\build\paths.js` and `skeleton-es2016\build\tasks\watch.js`

Comment: Ok. I get it now. Also, i cant reinstall all packages because my Internet's slow. I was able to reduce the watch task to 20 sec tough by removing bootstrap from config.js and package.json files.